# Effect of skewness in data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science-model, feature-scaling, distribution

I am preparing classification model. Many of numeric variables are positives skewed. Should I change a distribution of variables to be more Gaussian?

Comment: It depends on the model. Some models need input data to have a Gaussian distribution, other models don't care. The best you can do is try multiple models and pre-processing methods to see what works best. If you are using python with sklearn, this can be automated with GridSearchCV.

Comment: Please give more details so that we can understand the context: what kind of classification model? How do you want to change the distribution of your variables?

Answer (score 1):

Data does **not necessarily** have to be standardized and
mainly from the model, which we want to use.

Normality it's in many cases an **asumption**.
In this situation normality means that the error between the predictions and the actual answers is distributed normally.

Answer (score 0):

What model are you using?

Ideally, one should always scale / normalize data before feeding them into some ML / statistical model. By using Z-scores you should be able to control for skewness of your variables.

Comment: The z-score transformation would give data with a mean of $0$ and a variance of $1$, but what is the mechanism by which $z_i=(x_i-\bar{x})/s$ controls skewness? Perhaps you mean something different from how I interpret your comment, but the graph of exponential data that I just made looks just as skewed after I took the z-scores as before.

Comment: Please post your plot and any possible information we could find useful, and I'll update my answer.